# CXF In-Interceptor annotation is not working + JAX-RS

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-rs, interceptor

I have written a CustomValidationInterceptor. I want to configure this interceptor at service level with the use of annotations. Suppose, If I have exposed 5 services, and I want to configure the Interceptor for Only 1 of those service then how shall I do that

Following is my current code which is not firing the interceptor

```
@Service("someService")
@Path("somePath")
@InInterceptors(interceptors = { "com.telus.ffo.msl.service.impl.CustomValidationInterceptor" })
public class SystemCheckRestService {


    @POST
    @Path("/{phoneNumber}")
    @Produces({"application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
    public Response preRepairTest(@PathParam("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber) {
    // Code...
    }
}
```

Code snippet of My custom Interceptor is :

```
@Component
public class CustomValidationInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message>{

    public CustomValidationInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE); // Put this interceptor in this phase
    }

    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        // some code
     }

}
```